# Animated movie about Snow White, involving a scene with a comb dipped in poison

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation, snow-white

I absolutely can not find the movie anywhere and I’m hoping someone here can find it. It was an animated version of Snow White, most likely came out between 1990-2005.

It stayed more true to the original story where the queen tries three times to get rid of Snow. The biggest detail I can remember is a beautiful green comb with a handle that the queen dips in some sort of poison to attempt to kill Snow.

I’ve found a few versions that seem close but not quite right. I know it’s not the 1990 straight-to-DVD version, but the animation style is very similar. As far as I remember it was not directly associated with Disney. Does anyone recognize the movie or any information about it?

Comment: I do apologize that there isn’t much detail, it’s been a super long time since I have seen the movie.

Comment: Looks like there are a couple of different DTV versions from 1990. Are you ruling out _both_ of those? 1) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1075399/, 2) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5752586/?ref_=tt_sims_tt_i_3. The first one linked has a scene very similar to what you've described at [around the 39-40 minute mark](https://youtu.be/fhYSeK5w-uc?t=2356).

Comment: [Here's another DTV version](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1050263/?ref_=tt_sims_tt_i_3) from 1995 with a poisoned comb scene at [around the 27 minute mark](https://youtu.be/7VoZyscSJVg?t=1630).

Comment: [Another one from 1994](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0218611/) with a poison comb scene. https://youtu.be/rqdnY5A0EJw?t=1271

Comment: The one from 1994 is it! Thank you so much! I remember the two from 1990 and I did rule those out.

Comment: If you're so inclined, please consider marking my answer below as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 7):

As confirmed by the OP [in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259620/looking-for-a-movie-about-snow-white#comment714412_259620), this is ***[Snow White and the Magic Mirror](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0218611/)*** (1994).

From IMDB:

> In this comedic take on Snow White, the vain queen, jealous of Snow White's beauty, tries to kill her multiple times. A band of dwarfs, all spoofs of famous comedians, takes her in to protect her.

From the [NicThic Wiki](https://nicthic.fandom.com/wiki/Snow_White_and_the_Magic_Mirror):

> *Snow White and the Magic Mirror*, also known as *Princess Stories: Snow White and the Magic Mirror*, is a 1994 American animated direct-to-video film that was released on VHS on November 1, 1994 by United American Video Corporation as part of its UAV Gold banner; it was later included on the DVD releases of *The Secret of Anastasia*. This film received a ton of criticism for ripping off Disney’s *Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs*.

The scene with the poisoned comb can be viewed at the 21:11 mark in the video below.